# How can I change the screen size in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I am working on a Unity project. I started it on version 2018.3.6f1. The other day I installed version 2019.3.0a2 and this changed the screen size so now I have a white background at each side.

If I try going back to the size I had using the scale tool, it does not work so what do you recommend to change my screen size correctly or change it to its original one?

Here is a representation of my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRVH.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to a setting you can change from the top bar of the Game window, it effectively sets the screen size emulation within the editor to different values, it looks like you want to have 'Free' mode, but you can also check behaviours in any other resolution

[image]